# Max in a list and its index in Haskell -- in the case of a tie, I need the element closest to the head

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

My code as below
`(value, index) = maximumBy (comparing fst) (zip list [0..])`
works fine in most cases, however, in case of a tie, it returns the index that is closest to the tail, which is the opposite of what I want.
Namely, if the list is `xs = [2,7,3,7]`, I want it to return `(7,1)` instead of `(7,3)`. Is there an easy way to do it, or I need to rewrite it completely?

Comment: Your test currently is just `comparing fst` so it ignores the index (`snd`) altogether. You might want to use a more sophisticated test, that is one that also takes the index suitably into account.

Comment: `minimumBy (comparing (first Down)) $ zip [1,7,2,7] [0..]`. or `maximumBy (comparing (second Down)) $ ...`. although this depends on the index being in `Ord`.

Comment: @jpmarinier to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524955/remove-every-number-of-an-int-list-in-every-possible-way-with-recursion?noredirect=1#comment114099680_64524955) on the now deleted Q, it was amalloy that pointed to the guidelines, not me. according to their interpretation, I've committed an unpardonable sin by making the above comment as well.

Comment: @WillNess - yes, sorry for the confusion. I had just spotted my error when the question was being deleted right under my feet. So I did not get the time to redirect my comment to amalloy. SO is such a jungle :-) Anyway thanks for finding a way to come back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the source code for `maximumBy`

```
maximumBy :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> t a -> a
maximumBy cmp = foldl1 max'
  where max' x y = case cmp x y of
                        GT -> x
                        _  -> y
```

So by definition it returns the rightmost max element.
The most straightforward way to get the leftmost max element, I suppose, would be to define your own `maximumBy'` like so

```
maximumBy' cmp = fold1 max'
  where max' x y = case cmp x y of
                        LT -> y
                        _  -> x
```

All other ways redefine `max` in some way, much like how we did here.

That would give you:

```
> maximumBy' (comparing fst) (zip xs [0..])
> (7,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there an easy way to do it, or do I need to rewrite it completely ?*

If you insist on reusing the library `maximumBy` function, you can do it this way: replace the `fst` argument to `comparing` by something more appropriate.

For example, negate the indices to have the comparison result go the opposite way.

```
 λ> 
 λ> xs = [2,7,3,7]
 λ> 
 λ> maximumBy  (comparing (\(v,x) -> (v,-x)))  (zip xs [0..])
 (7,1)
 λ>
```

If you are familiar with the Haskell [Arrow](http://wiki.haskell.org/Arrow_tutorial) facility, the same idea can be expressed in more concise fashion:

```
 λ> 
 λ> import Control.Arrow
 λ> 
 λ> maximumBy  (comparing (second id))  (zip xs [0..])
 (7,3)
 λ> 
 λ> maximumBy  (comparing (second negate))  (zip xs [0..])
 (7,1)
 λ> 
 λ> maximumBy  (comparing (id *** negate))  (zip xs [0..])
 (7,1)
 λ>
```